# Swift tableView with images from API is lagging when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableView which I populate with images from an API, 
however, it is lagging quite a bit when scrolling. I've tried to use async & run on different threads but cannot get it right.. so how do I fix this? 
This is the cellForRowAt-func that I use to set image for every single cell.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let video = highlightsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.video = video

    do {

        let url = URL(string: self.highlightsArray[indexPath.row].thumbnail)!
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        cell.thumbnailImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
        cell.thumbnailImage.image = UIImage(named: "pllogo.jpg")
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: well, you're always downloading the images when scrolling. try caching it. there's a lot of library already existing for this kind of problems, unless you want to create your own then sure go ahead

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
```

blocks the main thread and redownloads the same image multiple times when scrolling , consider using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)